# Can $X{} function used outside queryString?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to use $X{} outside the queryString like this in jrxml

```
<parameter name="param_value" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[(" where $X{IN, country,country_param}")]]> </defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>

<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select user_id from user_profile $P{param_value}]]>
</queryString>
```

But I'm getting the error while evaluating param_value

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: X for class:...
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, the $X syntax only works inside of queryString.

However, all JasperReports is doing when it encounters $X is to translate it into a string before running the query. So `$X{IN, country,country_param}` becomes `country IN (country1, country2, ...)`

To solve your problem, you can generate the string yourself in Java and pass it to the report as a variable. Something like this:

```
if(countryList == null){
    countryList = defaultCountryList;
}

StringBuilder whereParam = new StringBuilder();
whereParam.append(country);
whereParam.append("IN (");
for(String s : countryList){
    whereParam.append("\""+s+"\"");
}
whereParam.append(")");

reportParameters.setParameter("where_param", whereParam.toString());
```

Then by using the `$P!` syntax you can place the string into the query. i.e:

```
<queryString>
<![CDATA[SELECT user_id FROM user_profile WHERE $P!{where_param}]]>
</queryString>
```

Unlike the `$P` syntax, `$P!` performs a simple string replacement before running the query, much like what $X is doing.